# How to add more parameter (eg. note) to a PayPal.me url?

Tags: paypal

With PayPal.me you can pre-select a payment with a username and amount, but it is possible to add other parameters?

PayPal.Me/username/amount/note/
PayPal.Me/username/100/ordernumber123456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with PayPal.me

For that type of functionality, instead log into http://www.paypal.com and check if you have the option to create a "Sell on Social" button at http://www.paypal.com/buttons

If you do not, a second alternative is to create a "Buy Now" button, leave the amount blank, do not change anything in the box of "Customize this button", and in Step 2 uncheck the option to save the button at PayPal. Then generate the code and switch to the "E-mail" tab.

Comment: When the service first started, it was possible to specify currency via GET parameters. They removed the UI for that and now it's impossible to find a `paypal.me` link with those parameters.

Comment: It's still possible to specify the currency, e.g. `https://paypal.me/%username%/12.34DKK`

Answer (score 4):

you can create link like this: paypal.me/shortlink/amount
exampls: paypal.me/johnpayments/25.00

Comment: Please reread the question. The OP already knows you can specify a username and amount. It's **other* features they are asking about.